# Getting NoTestsRemainException when I try to run test suites in junits 4.12

Tags: junit

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:107)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Share some more information

Comment: In our automation project we have the below test package 


@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(Itest1Category.class)
@SuiteClasses(AllTestSuite.class)
public class TESTINGTestSuite {

}                When executed the test suite through Junit , i am getting this exception :org.junit.runner.manipulation.NoTestsRemainException
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.filter(ParentRunner.java:394)

Comment: It dosent have any method with @Test annotation?

Comment: It does have many methods with @Test annotation.                             
    Error: org.junit.runner.manipulation.NoTestsRemainException
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.filter(ParentRunner.java:394)
 at org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories.<init>

Comment: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/manipulation/NoTestsRemainException.java - Check this out.It says "Thrown when a filter removes all tests from a runner" i think some how your test is not added when you are executing.